# How to get the selected values from d3.js range slider?

Tags: d3.js, slider, range

Hi i managed to get a range slider from internet and i just modified it. Now i want to know how to get the value from the range slider . My JSFIDDLE is http://jsfiddle.net/gdHB4/. If i selected the value from o.3 to 0.8 ,then i want to get the value 0.3 and 0.8 in two different variables. I also want to convert the x-axis of the slider to years(do only if possible for u, otherwise i will try). Thanks

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .extent([.3, .9])
   .on("brushstart", brushstart)
    .on("brush", brushmove)
    .on("brushend", brushend);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(height / 2)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d, i) { return i ? -Math.PI : Math.PI; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(0));

/*var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("text").text("working");
    */


var brushg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush);

brushg.selectAll(".resize").append("path")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," +  height / 2 + ")")
    .attr("d", arc);

brushg.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", height);

brushstart();
brushmove();

function brushstart() {
  svg.classed("selecting", true);
}

function brushmove() {
  var s = brush.extent();
  circle.classed("selected", function(d) { return s[0] <= d && d <= s[1]; });
}

function brushend() {
  svg.classed("selecting", !d3.event.target.empty());
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean "brush" when you say "range slider". You can get its extent by calling `brush.extent()`.

Comment: yes.. now only i see such a concept in d3. Please suggest some tutorial links for brush concepts for beginners.

Comment: The API documentation would have helped you with that.

Comment: Ok fine ,. thanks.. i will go through it

Comment: Hi managed to do that everything now. but i want to show the abbrevated name for month i did this through d3.time.format("%b") but it doesnt show the year instead it show jan.. I want to show the year whenever jan occurs .

Comment: My jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/s9kH3/ . when i split the month by 2 or 3 it override how to avoid it and make this automaticall changes depend upon the data.

Comment: You need a multi-scale time format, see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176

Comment: Hi, We are dong similar assignment where in we need to show average value of selected brushed part. How can we get it? Can you please hint or guide on this?